# Can PyCharm's IdeaVim plugin be persuaded to use hard tabs?

Tags: python, vim, pycharm, ideavim

I'm primarily a vim user, but at work most folks are using PyCharm, so I thought I'd at least give PyCharm a serious try.

To make the transition a little less...  well...  repetitively typed, I installed PyCharm's IdeaVim plugin.

However, our coding style -requires- hard tabs, not spaces (yes, it's the opposite of what most places do today), and I'm having a hard time getting IdeaVim to insert hard tabs instead of 4 spaces.

I've tried :set noexpandtab (and a :%retab), and I've tried ^V^I, but neither seems to be working.

Does anyone have IdeaVim doing hard tabs?  If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set "Use tab character" in "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Python"? Does everything work as expected with IdeaVim disabled? Please give a code example and your keystrokes where you would expect tabs, but got spaces instead.

Comment: I'd swear I did that, but I just revisited that setting and it wasn't set.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set "Use tab character" in "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Python"? Does everything work as expected with IdeaVim disabled? Please give a code example and your keystrokes where you would expect tabs, but got spaces instead.